# Is it possible to find Composite relation $S^{-1}\circ R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Given $A=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$,  $B=\left\{3,4,5,6\right\}$ and  $C=\left\{6,7,8,9\right\}$

A Relation $R \subset A \times B$ such that $xRy$ iff $4x \lt y$ and a Relation $S$ is defined as

$S \subset B \times C$ such that $ySz$ iff $2y \le z$ We have to find $S^{-1}oR$

we get $$R=\left\{(1,5),(1,6)\right\}$$

and $$S=\left\{(3,6),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9),(4,8),(4,9)\right\}$$

hence
$$S^{-1} \subset C \times B$$ is given by

$$S^{-1}=\left\{(6,3),(7,3),(8,3),(9,3),(8,4),(9,4)\right\}$$

Now my book gave answer as $$S^{-1}\circ R=\left\{(1,3)\right\}$$

But is $S^{-1}\circ R$ defined here?

Comment: Yes, note that $1R6$ and $6S^{-1}3$, and that's the only pair that matches.

Comment: But composite relation definition from wikipedia says that if $R \subseteq A \times B$ and $S \subseteq B \times C$  are two binary relations then $SoR =\left\{(x,z) \in A \times C \vert \exists y \in B :(x,y) \in A \times B and (y,z) \in B \times C \right\}$ such that

Comment: Good point. It seems that your book uses some wider definition of relation: "a set of ordered pairs".

Comment: so do you mean in that case any composition is defined?